# No GRASS folder on MacOS

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, mac

I am trying to get my GRASS plugin working and found that I have to set the path for it, but the path does not exist on my computer.

I tried uninstalling QGIS and reinstalling it and the problem was not fixed, still missing GRASS folder under `Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS`.

I have done the homebrew steps and it says everything went as it should but GRASS is not where it should be and I can't find it anywhere else. I am trying to get contour lines from QGIS to Fusion360 as a 3D model, is there another plugin I can use?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If GRASS didn't install when you installed QGIS you can install it separately then go into the the GRASS plugin settings in QGIS and point the plugin to the fresh GRASS installation.

The easiest way to install GRASS on Mac is through homebrew:  https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compiling_on_MacOSX_using_homebrew

Comment: I have recently edited the wiki page and we now got it installed successfully. A step was simply missing... now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When I use homebrew I get then error "X11Requirement unsatisfied!" on the last step of actually getting GRASS.

I got it working, I actually had to download xQuartz with a link through Homebrew Cask that was hidden in the error given to me.

Comment: Have you generated duplicate accounts?  If so, please follow these directions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I got it working, I actually had to download xQuartz with a link through Homebrew Cask that was hidden in the error given to me.

Comment: Now I have no idea where GRASS is... I still can't use it in QGIS